# What methods are there to produce map tiles for google maps?

Tags: google-maps, tiles

newbie to stack exchange here.

I'm currently using the automatic tile cutter found [here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Automatic_Tile_Cutter) to make the standard 256x256 tiles required to make a custom map type for my map. The map tile cutter script feels quite clumsy to use, and I quickly use up all of my machine's 4GB of ram to open photoshop and use it. That, and it's very bothersome to pad my images with empty space on the top and bottom so that it's positioned correctly.

Does anyone know of other tools which can be used to make tiles for google maps?

Comment: I think this is a great question, and would like to know which methods can be coordinated across multiple computers.

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5101/using-gdal-to-cut-tiles

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/). I have used it with Google Maps. It has worked great for me.

Comment: That was my answer!, I've had similar success.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried MapTiler ([www.maptiler.org](http://www.maptiler.org/))? Should be able to get the tiles you seek (256X256 - not sure).I'm experimenting with it for 'teach-yourself' webmapping with openlayers, works great.

Comment: I gave MapTiler a try quite a while ago but couldn't get it to work for me. Could give it another go.

Answer (score 5):

Mapcruncher (Mircosoft)
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/mapcruncher/
(designed for Virtual Earth/Live Maps and now Bing Maps)

But can be used for Google Maps as use the same projection.
Easy to use and FREE.

Answer (score 5):

If you have [FME](http://www.safe.com), then it will do it with its WebMapTiler transformer.

**[Here](http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/Rasterization_for_Web_Mapping_Platforms)** and [**here**](http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Web_Map_Tile_Cache_in_SQL_Server) are a couple of examples

To answer Kirk's comment, FME Server is capable of coordinating this over multiple machines (or multiple engines on one machine). See the first link above for some nice graphs.

Eight engines will bring the time for zoom level 8 (24,500 tiles) from 120 minutes to 20 minutes. Zoom level 11 (1,000,000 tiles) can be produced in about 380 minutes (again with 8 engines). I don't know that you could do that on one machine.

FME Server is also capable of running in the cloud - WeoGeo for example [**tried the above scenario**](http://blog.weogeo.com/2009/06/19/scaling-fme-engines-on-weogeo/) in that way.

NB: I do work for Safe Software, makers of FME and FME Server

Comment: Great software use it everyday (FME2010/11 via workbench), though maybe outside the posters budget.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I didn't know about that aspect of FME server. Also thanks for disclosing your relationship to FME.

Comment: Thanks for that Mark. I have access to FME Workbench 2009. I've just had a play with the VirtualEarthTiler transformer but for some reason, it believes my raster which I've projected to web mercator with GDALwarp is something else, 'Nonearthmeter'. Do you have a tool you use to project raster data to web mercator?

Answer (score 4):

I would +1 on maptiler. I've used it with small-ish raster datasets. If you're not afraid of the command line, it's just a GUI for GDAL2Tiles, which you could use directly.

Answer (score 4):

[MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/) might also be an option

Answer (score 3):

I have used Global Mapper (http://www.globalmapper.com/) in the past for all my tiling.  It can do Google format tiles, along with Bing, KML and World Wind as well.  Pretty friendly and is not too expensive.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Avenza](http://www.avenza.com)'s [Geographic Imager](http://www.avenza.com/geographic-imager) plugin for Adobe Photoshop to tile your images right inside Photoshop