# Creating custom maps for Garmin Oregon 600

Tags: gps, garmin

I have a Garmin Oregon 600 GPS receiver and a map I made in QGIS. Where can I find a step-by-step guide to getting this map onto my GPS unit? A static JPEG or PNG map is fine since I'm not interested in keeping connections to the map / feature services from the field; no cellular service or wi-fi anyway.

I could create the map in ArcMap 10.3 or ArcGIS Pro if that makes life easier but my preference is to leave it in QGIS.

Comment: I use base-camp myself but can be done in QGIS http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103776/uploading-maps-to-gps-forestry-maps-roads-trails-hydro-polygons

Comment: Other related questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62188/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92354/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53988/

Answer (score 1):

There is a ArcGIS Tool for converting Maps into Garmin Custom Maps:

https://bitbucket.org/wankoelias/maptogarmincustommap/src