# Import raster data in GPS with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.1, gps

How do I see the map on GPS as a background layer?

In QGIS, I could see the map which is converted from shapefile and raster data on QGIS with "Garmin Custom Map".

I need to do the similar thing through ArcGIS.

GIS: Arc info 10.1
GPS: Garmin GPS map 62sc

Any comment or advice is very helpful.

Comment: Are you asking how to add the raw data from your GPS or do you already have it on your computer? You'll most likely want [Adding XY data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) which you can then export as a shapefile. Why are you asking for raster though?

Comment: Do you want a map exported from ArcMap to be usable in your Garmin GPS?  If so export to a georeferenced tif, then use OkMap's Garmin tile utility to convert that to a custom kmz map usable in your Garmin.  ArcGIS's tools for converting from tif to kmz are clumsy.  OkMap is free.

Comment: Paul   sorry for unclear explanation. My purpose is export GIS data(raster) to GPS.

Comment: Johns    I can convert data via of some tools(QGIS or OkMap, etc). I hope to export data from ArcGIS to GPS directly. If you have any Idea, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a script to do this here: [Exporting 3GB ArcGIS Raster to KML without losing resolution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23676/exporting-3gb-arcgis-raster-to-kml-without-losing-resolution/144212#144212)

and since then another user posted a script here:
https://bitbucket.org/wankoelias/maptogarmincustommap/src/master/

they both do a pretty similar thing.. reproject, tile, write a text file, package. Mine works on an image and his works on an mxd.

Answer (score -1):

1. In ArcCatalog or the Catalog window, right-click the geodatabase, and click Import > Raster Datasets.
2. Click the Input Rasters browse button Browse to navigate to the raster datasets you want to import.
3. Select the raster dataset you want to import and click Add.
   You can use the SHIFT or CTRL keys to select more than one raster dataset.

Repeat steps 2 and 3 to add raster datasets from different locations.
Click the Output Geodatabase browse button Browse to set the output geodatabase if it has not already been specified.
Optionally, type a configuration keyword.
Click OK.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  I am not sure this answers the question of how to get raster data from ArcMap into a Garmin GPS device - you don't appear to have mentioned the GPS device at all.

Comment: I don't think Garrmin GPS devices even recognize the geodatabase format.