# Raster to KML convesrion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, kml, arctoolbox

How raster data can be converted to KML? I have searched but could not find any answer. Are there any tools in Arc toolbox for such process ?

Answer (score 2):

In the search box in ArcMap type, "To KML"; there are two tools.

1. Layer to KML: "This tool converts a feature or raster layer into a KML file containing a translation of Esri geometries and symbology. This file is compressed using ZIP compression, has a .kmz extension, and can be read by any KML client including ArcGIS Explorer, ArcGlobe, and Google Earth."
2. Map to KML: "This tool converts a map document into a KML file containing a translation of Esri geometries and symbology. This file is compressed using ZIP compression, will have a .kmz extension, and can be read by any KML client including ArcGIS Explorer, ArcGlobe, and Google Earth."

Comment: These tools were clearly created to convert images for use in Minecraft.... have you been satisfied with the results? IMO this is only an answer in theory.

Answer (score 1):

Still not aware of any Arc tool that does this satisfactorily, but I posted a script here:
[Exporting 3GB ArcGIS Raster to KML without losing resolution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23676/exporting-3gb-arcgis-raster-to-kml-without-losing-resolution/144212#144212)