# Rasterizing polygon grid in Python (geopandas & rasterio)

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, rasterization, geocube

I am trying to rasterize a custom polygon grid with one or more columns. Preferably I'd like to create multi-band rasters from multiple `GeoDataFrame` columns (in polygon grid), but I have got stuck even with one layer.

Here's [a script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316460/23274) about creating some arbitrary polygon grid in geopandas. `GeoDataFrame` and then my attempt to rasterize it, largely following [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/151861/23274)

```
# Load libraries
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from rasterio import features
from rasterio.plot import show
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Create a Demo Grid
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = 1,1,5,5
lenght = 1
wide = 1

cols = list(range(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), wide)) 
rows = list(range(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), lenght)) 
rows.reverse()

polygons = []
for x in cols:
    for y in rows:
        polygons.append( Polygon([(x,y), (x+wide, y), (x+wide, y-lenght), (x, y-lenght)]) )

g = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':polygons})

# Create a column to print out
g['id'] = g.index
g.plot(column = 'id')
```

Here is the output I would like to have as a raster:

[image: Polygon image]

To do that, I have tried:

```
# Create raster from a grid
out_fn = "raster.tif"

b = g.unary_union.bounds
width = int(b[2]-b[0])
heigth = int(b[3]-b[1])

out_shape = (heigth, width)
out_array = np.zeros(out_shape, dtype = 'uint8')

# Create a metadata directory 
meta = {'driver': 'GTiff',
        'dtype': 'uint8',
        'nodata': 255, 
        'width': width, 
        'height': heigth,
        'count': 1,
        'crs': {'init': 'epsg:4326'} , 
        'tiled': False, 
        'compress': 'lzw', 
        'interleave': 'band'}

with rasterio.open(out_fn, 'w', **meta) as out:

    # Create a generator for geom and value pairs 
    grid_cell = ((geom,value) for geom, value in zip(g.geometry, g.id))

    burned = features.rasterize(shapes=grid_cell, fill=0, out_shape = out_shape)
    print("Burned: \n", burned)
    out.write_band(1, burned)

# Read the output back in and check
r = rasterio.open(out_fn)
show(r)
```

[image: Raster output]

Nevertheless, the output is not what I expected. Value and the coordinates are both erroneous.

I do not understand what happens to the zip object, which looks totally fine.

```
list(zip(g.geometry, g.id))
Out[7]: 
[(<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459ecf8>, 0),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459ee48>, 1),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459ee80>, 2),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459eeb8>, 3),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459eef0>, 4),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459ef28>, 5),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459ef60>, 6),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459ef98>, 7),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459efd0>, 8),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459ee10>, 9),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459eda0>, 10),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac459edd8>, 11),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac45a60f0>, 12),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac45a6128>, 13),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac45a6160>, 14),
 (<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x21ac45a6198>, 15)]

burned
Out[8]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  7, 11],
       [ 0,  2,  6, 10],
       [ 0,  1,  5,  9],
       [ 0,  0,  4,  8]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

I have three main and one extra questions:

1. Where in the code I am doing the error(s)?
2. How should I properly define the metadata without a template raster?
3. Is there a way to rasterize multiple bands simultaneously (so *n* columns from the GeoDataFrame, not just one)?
4. why does the g.geometry column contain 5 coordinate pairs, first and last being the same, and not 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will start with #2 and #3. There is a tool out there called geocube: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/index.html. It will handle all of the rasterization for you in a simpler process and handles multiple columns of data.

https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/grid_to_vector_map.html

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube


xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = 1,1,5,5
lenght = 1
wide = 1

cols = list(range(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), wide)) 
rows = list(range(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), lenght)) 
rows.reverse()

polygons = []
for x in cols:
    for y in rows:
        polygons.append( Polygon([(x,y), (x+wide, y), (x+wide, y-lenght), (x, y-lenght)]) )

g = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    {"data1": list(range(len(polygons))), "data2": list(range(10, 10+len(polygons)))},
    geometry=polygons,
    crs={"init": "epsg:4326"}
)

cube = make_geocube(vector_data=g, resolution=(1, -1))
```

This will provide the data in a gridded xarray interface with the proper geospatial metadata set.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (x: 4, y: 4)
Coordinates:
  * y            (y) float64 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5
  * x            (x) float64 4.5 3.5 2.5 1.5
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Data variables:
    data1        (y, x) float64 15.0 11.0 7.0 3.0 14.0 ... 1.0 12.0 8.0 4.0 0.0
    data2        (y, x) float64 25.0 21.0 17.0 13.0 24.0 ... 22.0 18.0 14.0 10.0
```

The data looks like:

[image: cubed raster]

You can then export each column of the data to a tif with:

```py
cube.data1.rio.to_raster("data1.tif")
```

> 1) Where in the code I am doing the error(s)

The main issue is that you are not adding the `transform` for the raster that defines the resolution of the grid cells and its location.

> 4) why does the g.geometry column contain 5 coordinate pairs, first and last being the same, and not 4?)

This is because shapely is closing the loop of the polygon automatically for you.