# CRSerror in geocube make_geocube

Tags: geocube

I get the error below when i run the example by snowman2 here [Rasterizing polygon grid in Python (geopandas & rasterio)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322589/rasterizing-polygon-grid-in-python-geopandas-rasterio/328327#328327)

CRSError: CRS is invalid: <Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:

- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
  Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
  Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

Comment: You need to provide more context. What version of python, operation system, installation method. Also, a code snippet with a sample dataset would help.

Comment: I run exactly the one here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322589/rasterizing-polygon-grid-in-python-geopandas-rasterio/328327#328327.
I have python 3.7, windows 10 and i installed via conda-forge.

Comment: Are you able to provide more information about your errors? Version of rasterio, fiona, GDAL, rioxarray, geocube?

Comment: i installed a newer version of geocube which came with all dependencies. It works fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked 