# Convert GeoDataframe to Raster

Tags: python, geopandas, geocube

I want to convert a GeoPandas GeoDataframe to raster (.tif).
I have multiple attributes in my GeoDataframe and want to create a raster using  a single field from the attribute table. The underlying vector format are 16x16m square polygons, which should be represented later by a single pixel.

Up to now I haven't found any straight-forward solutions or useful tutorials, so I am looking for some helpful answers or hints of where to find practical information.

I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.8.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide some of your python code? See this q also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151339/rasterize-a-shapefile-with-geopandas-or-fiona-python

Comment: Take the centroid of each polygon and run it through scipy's [griddata()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) using a 16m grid, then use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to write it out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be interested in geocube (https://github.com/corteva/geocube):

Examples: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/examples.html

```py
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

gdf = geopandas.read_file(...)
out_grid= make_geocube(vector_data=gdf, measurements=["column_name"], resolution=(-16, 16)) #for most crs negative comes first in resolution
out_grid["column_name"].rio.to_raster("my_rasterized_column.tif")
```