# Reproject tfw without creating a new raster file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I have a quite big amount of georeferenced .tif with their .tfw in one folder. The orignal CRS is Gauss-Krueger, and now I want to reproject them to UTM.
My approach so far is to use gdalwarp:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14\bin\gdalwarp.exe" -s_srs EPSG:31467 -t_srs EPSG:3044 -multi -co TFW=TRUE -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS "%mypath_import%!infile!" "%mypath_rasterUTM%!outfile!"
```

Ergo, I get a lot of new TIFFs and the process needs a lot of time. Is there a way to just reproject the .tfw into UTM coordinates? I think it's quite a waste of processing power/disk space to create a whole new TIFF!

Comment: Well, in theory, you could do that, but it would completely destroy your data. Done correctly, reprojection is *supposed* to use a great deal of processing power and disk space.

Comment: if you compress the output it will take up less space - or may be you could get by with VRTs which are much smaller?

Comment: LZW compress > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/should-gdal-be-set-to-produce-geotiff-files-with-compression-which-algorithm-sh